# How to choose suitable filters in ASP.NET MVC for this scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter, authorize-attribute

I understand different types of filters are available in ASP.NET MVC. Now I am confused about the following 3 types of filters. I have to use custom filters in my code.

1. Authentication Filter
2. Authorization Filter
3. Action Filter

I have users, roles and their permissions (read, add, delete) in 4 different tables.

Which filter method I should choose?

When I did a search, I am able to found some of them using Action filters as

```
public class MyFirstCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   ....
}
```

- OnActionExecuting - my code goes here for role and permmsion - is this correct way ?
- OnResultExecuting

But some article use

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

        //my code goes here for role and permission check - is this correct way ?  
    }
}
```

I want to check user is eligible to execute particular action based on roles & permission in db.

Now I am confused with all these methods. For me, all are similar. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have not told us what the purpose of the filter is

Comment: I want to check user is elligible to excute particular action based on roles & permssion in db

Comment: You can use either - `AuthorizeAttribute` inherits from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` (which in turn implements `IAuthorizationFilter`).

Comment: **Authentication** is about finding out **who you ARE** - e.g. this is about figuring out your user name, making sure the provided credentials are correct etc.; **Authorization** is about **what you're allowed to do** once you've been authenticated - once I know it's you (and I've verified it), then authorization allows me to define what you can do - which functions you can execute, what data you can see etc.

Comment: I agree my doubt is, can we get same behavior this with 'ActionFilterAttribute'